# A certain png image disappeared from layout

Tags: android, layout, png, imagebutton

i have a layout xml which has 16 image button.

one png image which is declared in that layout does not show in activity.(only android 2.2 / 2.3)
when i add dummy image in drawable, strangely enough, previous image will be gone.
(when two dummy image, two before image will be gone...)
in eclipse graphical layout, i can see the image of disappeared on android phone.

i already checked R file has a declaration of disappeared image.
Does anyone know about what's going on about this issue?

i would appreciate your support.

For example in code following...
ImageButton which tag is 3 is not showing on screen, not even clickable.
but when i add dummy button such as button_999, that actually not used in app, then the ImageButton with tag 2 is disappeared and ImageButton with tag 3 is showing this time.
if i add one more dummy button like button_998, then ImageButton with tag1 will disappear.

here is the style

```
<style name="layoutStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:orientation">horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">3dip</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">3dip</item>
    <item name="android:baselineAligned">false</item>
</style>
<style name="buttonStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dip</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:adjustViewBounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">#00000000</item>
    <item name="android:scaleType">centerInside</item>
    <item name="android:padding">2dip</item>
    <item name="android:onClick">onClick</item>
</style>
```

and layout file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    style="@style/layoutStyle"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dip">
    <ImageButton
        style="@style/buttonStyle"
        android:tag="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescription"
        android:src="@drawable/button_selector_1"/>
    <ImageButton
        style="@style/buttonStyle"
        android:tag="2"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescription"
        android:src="@drawable/button_selector_2"/>
    <ImageButton
        style="@style/buttonStyle"
        android:tag="3"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescription"
        android:src="@drawable/button_selector_3"/>
<LinearLayout
    style="@style/layoutStyle"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dip">
    <ImageButton
        style="@style/buttonStyle"
        android:tag="4"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescription"
        android:src="@drawable/button_selector_5"/>
    <ImageButton
        style="@style/buttonStyle"
        android:tag="5"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescription"
        android:src="@drawable/button_selector_4"/>
    <ImageButton
        style="@style/buttonStyle"
        android:tag="6"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescription"
        android:src="@drawable/button_selector_6"/>
…… and so on(total 6 child layout)
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: paste your layout file.

Comment: i added the code. any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Clean up the project and try again

Answer (score 1):

By Which code you assigned the image for the Buttons?

Are you assigning dynamically or static images?

If you are using static images means, store the images in the Drawable folder and clean-up the project.
then assign the image for each button as follow...

```
           <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrapcontent"
            android:layout_height="wrapcontent"
            android:background="@drawable/img1"
            android:text="Button" />
```

Comment: using static image. and thats already stored in drawable folder.

Comment: Paste yours code in yours question, then only we can discuss clearly

Comment: i just added code and simple explaination. please take a look at it.